React native with backend
After learning React Native, I decided to build a big project. For this project, I will need a backend. Can I use Node.js, Express.js, and MySQL for the backend? I want to save registered users' information and then allow them to log in using the backend information.
Also, is it possible to upload the backend to a real website or page? So whenever I install the app on my Android device, or someone downloads it from the Play Store, they can register there and then log in, and save all their information and changes. If my question is unclear, please let me know, and I'll do my best to clarify."
if anyone has enough time to help me understand all this things I will be thankfull.

You can use every backend technology you want, this includes Node.js, express and MySQL, yes.
I am not sure if I understand your second question.
Your backend is not hosted or uploaded to a website or page. If you choose to stick with Node.js, express and MySQL, without any SaaS service, that parts will run on a server, and your mobile app makes http requests to that server. There are multiple options to host your backend (AWS, Azure, DigitalOcean, etc.)
I would not suggest to implement authentication and authorization by yourself though, there are already production ready SaaS solutions (Okta, Firebase). You could also look into Firebase functions (or any other serverless function provider) to get rid of your express backend altogether.
Also i would highly suggest you build a small app before your big project.

Thank you for your fast answer and first I will try to do a small app as you suggested me. could you help me understand more things,because Okta as well as firebase are new to me and I think I have many things to learn in the backend so if you could give me your mail , or whatsapp or viber I would contact you there and explain my questions
